# How to show that $\gamma_{i}(G) $/$\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ has finite exponent

Tags: group-theory

I want to prove:

> Suppose that $G$=$AF$ where $A$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$ and $F$ is a finite subgroup of $G$. Then $\gamma_{i}(G) $/$\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ has finite exponent for every i $\ge 2$.

or $\gamma_i G=[\gamma _{i-1} G, G],\ \gamma_1 = G$ members of the lower central series of $G$.

Any sort of help would be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\gamma_0(G)=1$

Comment: lower central series of group $G$  is the chain of subgroups ($\gamma_{i}(G) $ ) for $i \ge 1$defined by $\gamma_i G=[\gamma _{i-1} G, G]$, $\ \gamma_1$ = $G$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a consequence of the following result. Suppose that a finite group $F$ acts on an abelian group $B$. Let $C = [F,B] = \langle b^{-1}b^f \mid b \in B, f \in F \rangle$. Suppose that $F$ centralizes both $B/C$ and $C$. The $C$ has exponent dviding that of $F$. This follows from $[f^k,b] = [f,b]^k$ for all $f \in F$, $b \in B$, because $[f,b] \in C$, which is centralized by $F$.

We have $\gamma_2(FA) = \gamma_2(F)[A,F]$, $\gamma_3(FA) = \gamma_3(F)[A,F,F]$, $\ldots$, $\gamma_k(FA) = \gamma_k(F)[A,F,\ldots,F] = [A,F^{(k-1)}]$ (meaning $F$ repeated $k-1$ times).

So it is enough to prove that  $[A,F^{(k)}]/[A,F^{(k+1)}]$ has finite exponent for all $k \ge 1$. To do that, apply the result above with $B = [A,F^{(k-1)}]/[A,F^{(k+1)}]$ and $C = [A,F^{(k)}]/[A,F^{(k+1)}]$.

Comment: @DarekHolt thank u, why we suppose that $F$ centralizes both $A/B$ and $B$,

Comment: My notation was confusing because my $A$ was not the same as the original $A$. So I have changed that and added more explanation.

Comment: @DarekHolt Thank u, good explanation